# Why am I receiving import error for file that is clearly there

Tags: python

My python file looks like this:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append("../..")
sys.path.append("..")
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
#import pdb
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import copy

from tslib import tsUtils
from tslib.src.synthcontrol.syntheticControl import RobustSyntheticControl
from tslib.src.synthcontrol.multisyntheticControl import MultiRobustSyntheticControl
```

But i keep receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testScriptMultiSynthControlSVDV1.1.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tslib import tsUtils
ImportError: cannot import name 'tsUtils'
```

While the tsUtils file is clearly inside the src folder. Any idea as to why I'm getting "cannot import name" error would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you `import tslib`? If so, afterwards, do a `print(dir(tslib))` and see what's in it.

Comment: I am able to import tslib and this prints out  '_TZ_FORMAT', '_UNITS', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__date_to_millisecond_ts', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__timedelta_millis', '__title__', '__version__', 'argparse', 'calendar', 'date_from_utc', 'date_from_utc_ts', 'delta', 'dt', 'main', 'os', 'parse_input', 'parse_to_timestamp', 'print_function', 'pytz', 're', 'render_date', 'render_delta', 'render_delta_from_now', 'six', 'sys', 'utc', 'utc_millisecond_timestamp', 'version']

Comment: That's kind of hard to read…but it doesn't look like `tsUtils` is defined.

Comment: My file states "from tslib import tsUtils" and is inside the src folder. What else has to be done to define tsUtils?

Comment: My suggest assumed `tsUtils` was something defined in the `tslib` module. If instead it's a package, you probably need to add an `__init__.py` _file_ to the `tsUtils` package _directory_ — you may also need to have an `import tsUtils` in this `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir(module)` lists all members of a file/module. From the print result, it is obvious that you do not have a member called `tsUtils`.

Basically you are trying to import some member/attribute which is not defined in that module/file.

Ensure you are working with right version of files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that first uninstall tsUtils using `pip uninstall` command then install again using `pip install` and restart your system.